# Emberjs reuseable modal

Tags: javascript, ember.js, modal-dialog

**My goal:**

I want to make a compact, reuseable modal. It should take a template name, and render in a modal,

**What i got so far:**

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mehabivu/6/edit

**How it works:**

- App.ApplicationRoute has an action, which takes a template name.
- It renders it into {{ outlet modal }}
- I can use this action
  application wide, and reuse templates

My problem:

- I dont know how to wrap the outlet into a div or something (to add
  css), and show/hide it.
- Maybe there is a better practice (component?)
  to do this

Comment: For the templates that will be rendered in the modal, will they _always_ be rendered in the modal? Or will they sometimes be rendered normally in their parent outlet?

Comment: Sometimes in the parent outlet. The idia is to have it as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your on the right path. Pretty much exactly what Ember says to do in their cookbook: http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

Wrapping/styling the modal can be done via the view you render into the outlet. Right now your `menu2` template doesn't have a view.

```
App.Menu2View = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'section',
  classNames: ['modal']
});
```

The above makes the containing tag a `section` and adds the `modal` css class to that container `section`.

I've updated your JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mehabivu/7/edit